Equivalence in $l_q$ spaces
Let $\theta \in (0,1)$ and $1\leq q<\infty$. Let $\lambda=(\lambda_n)$ a sequence of real (or complex) numbers such that $$||(2^{-n\theta}\lambda_n)||_q<\infty.$$ Now, let $\beta=(\beta_n)$ another sequence of positive real numbers. I want to prove that if $M>0$ $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\lambda_n|\beta_n\leq M||(2^{-n\theta}\lambda_n)||_q,$$ for all such sequences $\lambda$, then $$||(2^{n\theta}\beta_n)||_{q'}\leq M,$$ where $1/q+1/q=1$. One implication is trivial since $$\sum |\lambda_n|\beta_n=|(\lambda_n\beta_n)||_1\leq ||(2^{-n\theta}\lambda_n)||_q||(2^{n\theta}\beta_n)||_{(1-1/q)^{-1}}\leq M||(2^{-n\theta}\lambda_n)||_q.$$ But i can't prove the other one. It seems trivial like the other but i can't conclude it. Thanks in advance!

For example, if $\lambda_1 = 1$, $\lambda_i = 0$ for $i \neq 1$, $\beta_2 = 1$, $\beta_i = 0$ for $i \neq 2$, then left part is true for any $M$, but right isn't.

So it's false? Is an statement from Luc Tartar's An Introduction to Sobolev Spaces and Interpolation Spaces, page 197.

IIUC, in the book corresponding part is "$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \alpha_n \beta_n \leq M|2^{-\sigma n} \alpha_n|q$ for all sequences $\alpha_n$ is equivalent to $|2^{\theta n} \beta_n|{q'} \leq M$" - this differs from your statement that the left inequality has to hold for all $\lambda_n$, not just one.

Yeah, sorry I read It wrong. Edited!
